# Choice of delta-neighbors in Balloon Hash algorithm

Tags: password-hashing, balloon

Reference Document: https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/027.pdf

According to appendix D section 4 definition 27

> each vertex in V has predecessors sampled independently and uniformly at random from the set U

It appears from the pseudo-code in section 3.1 step 2b, and the reference code given on [GitHub](https://github.com/henrycg/balloon/blob/master/libballoon/hash_state.c) `hash_state_mix()`, that this has been implemented by the authors as some form of squeezing bits out of the hash function; however my question is could it just as easily have been done with Mersenne Twister or is there another reason why the hash is required?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Mersenne twister or any other non-cryptographic PRNG, then it is conceivable that an adversary could exploit some pattern in the Mersenne twister's outputs to find a shortcut to reversing the resulting hash.  Cryptographic PRNGs are designed so that despite decades of efforts, cryptanalysts have been unable to find *any* patterns in their outputs that are even *detectable*, let alone exploitable in context.

Don't use the Mersenne twister!  It's also bad as a non-cryptographic PRNG because it is expensive to initialize and requires a multi-kilobyte state, so it discourages parallelism and reproducible subtrees of computations.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the PRNG in this case must be a CS one since the only thing the PRNG does is select which blocks to pull out; however Mersenne Twister as you point out has other issues which makes it a poor choice. Is there maybe another low-overhead PRNG that's uniformly random over `uint64_t`

Comment: @Gregory What motivates you to change the PRNG?  Any change to a non-cryptographic PRNG requires careful analysis to determine whether it affects security, and renders your balloon-hash variant incompatible with everyone else's idea of balloon-hash.

Comment: The lack of implementation documentation. As far as I can tell the PRNG used is `hash(salt)[i..i+d];i+=d+1`, but what happens when d runs off the end?

Comment: besides it's already going to be 'incompatible' because in the GitHub code: `neighbor % s->n_blocks` has pigeonholes